# What is a reliable way to automate FTP upload of 'the newest file in directory X'?

Tags: centos, ftp

I have this folder full of files.

Once per day, I want the newest of the files to be FTPed automatically to a file server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a short script, get the filename via this line:

```
newestfilename=`ls -t $dir| head -1`
```

(assuming `$dir` is the directory you're interested in), then feed `$filename` to your FTP command, and of course, `cron` this script to run once a day.

If you have `ncftp`, you can use the following command to `ftp` the file:

```
ncftpput -Uftpuser -Pftppasswd ftphost /remote/path $dir/$newestfilename
```

Without ncftp, this may work:

```
ftp -u ftp://username:passwd@ftp.example.com/path/to/remote_file $dir/$newestfilename
```

Comment: Quick question, if I change 'head -1' to 'head -2' will that get the second to newest file? I just want to make sure I don't grab a file that is mid-write.

Comment: No if you want the second file, you'd replace `head -1` with `head -2 | tail -1` :)

Comment: It worth note, that piping `ls` is not good in case filename contains smthing exotic, ex, '\n`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Locating the newest file

The easiest way to find the newest file in a directory is to use zsh and its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `om` to sort by modification time and `[1]` to pick the most recent match.

```
upload /path/to/dir/*(om[1])
```

There's no good, portable method. The only portable method is to use `ls -t` to list files by date and parse the result, but [parsing `ls` is fraught with dangers](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Do this only if you're sure that your file names contain no newlines or non-printable characters.

```
upload "$(ls -t /path/to/dir | head -n 1)"
```

#### FTP upload

For the upload, there are many tools. A commonly installed one is [curl](http://curl.haxx.se).

```
curl -T /path/to/local/file ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/dir
```

Another approach is to mount the remote directory as a filesystem, for example with [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net).

```
mkdir ftp.example.com
curlftpfs ftp.example.com ftp.example.com
cp -p /path/to/local/file ftp.example.com/remote/dir/
```

#### Automating the task

Add a [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry to perform the task every day. Run `crontab -e` and add a line like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
42 3 * * * curl -T /path/to/dir/*(om[1]) ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my selfmade script:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

SRCFOLDER="$1"
mountpoint="/home/$(whoami)/ftp"
mkdir "$mountpoint" > /dev/null 2>&1 # temporary ftp path

if [ $(whoami) == "root" ]
    then
        echo "Dont execute as root!"
        exit -1
fi

if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: terser (/source/folder)"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "${SRCFOLDER: -1}" != "/" ] # adds a "/" at end of path
    then 
        SRCFOLDER+="/"
fi

if [ -e "$SRCFOLDER" ]
    then
        FILE=$(ls -t1 $SRCFOLDER | head -n 1)
        echo "Newest file is: $FILE"
        if [ $FILE == "" ]
            then
            echo "The folder $SRCFOLDER is empty!"
        fi
        echo "Mounting ftp..."
        curlftpfs "username:password@ip.ad.re.ss" "$mountpoint" "-o" "disable_eprt" # if you use tls(port 22) do: "disable_eprt,tlsv1"
        echo "Mounted FTP"
        echo "Copying to ftp..."
        cp "$SRCFOLDER$FILE" "$mountpoint/path/" # after "$mountpoint/" enter your path for your backups
        echo "Copied to ftp"
        sleep 2
        fusermount -u $mountpoint
        echo "Unmounted ftp"
        sleep 3
        rmdir "$mountpoint"
else
    echo "The folder $SRCFOLDER does not exist!"
fi
```

!Edit the lines 33 & 36! (ftpconnection & path on ftpserver)

Just put it into /usr/bin/* or /sbin/* and execute it with the filename and sourcefolder. e.g.:

`scriptname /home/archuser/backups/`

another way:

Put the script in a file and do following:

`./scriptname /home/archuser/backups/`

or

`bash scriptname /home/archuser/backups/`

Just make a CronJob for this and you're a lucky man :)